# Como implementar um menu bootstrap em um projeto Angular?

Tags: bootstrap-3, angular

coloquei o seguinte código e não funcionou;

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Era para ter ficado assim:

[Navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h)

está minhas configurações do meu Angular, será que está faltando alguma coisa?
está no arquivo **.angular-cli.json**

```
  "styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",

        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [ "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/collapse.js"],
```

Comment: tem algum erro no console? tenha em mente que mudanças no anuglar-cli.json requerem que você reinicie o servidor. Tenta seguir este tutorial -> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap

Comment: eu segui essa instalação, não aparece mensagens de erros no console, a maioria das implementações do bootstrap funcionam, mas esse da navegação não está funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, jQuery deverá ser também ser incluido antes da utilização do collapse.js ou utilize [Bootstrap UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) se não pretender incluir jQuery no projeto angular.